# remove sensitive data but not file from git history

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a file that once contained sensitive config information.  I move that config info out into another file that isn't under version control.  I want to keep the other file under version control, but I want to remove its history because one can easily browse the source on github and find the sensitive information in previous commits.  What's the best way to do this?  I'm only seeing how to remove the file itself from version control and clear its history.

A little new to git, so pardon the newbieness.

Comment: Very common question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/872565/1286639

Comment: Github has a [post](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) to do just this. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at this article https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Pretty much says this command

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Will remove the history of `Rakefile` from git. However, they go ahead and add that file to their gitignore. You should probably skip that part since you want to keep the file in version control.

Comment: An explanation of what that actually does would be great.

Comment: The linked article explains how to remove a file. The OP's question title says to not remove a file.

Comment: @TylerCollier if you read my answer it states not to add the file to `gitignore` since that will take it out of version control. This will remove the file from history thus allowing the sensitive data to be removed.

Comment: The OP already knows how to do that: `I'm only seeing how to remove the file itself from version control and clear its history.` I think he wants to remove only the sensitive information from the history, but not the history itself.

Comment: Holy crap. Whatever happened to a simple right click remove history. Insanely complex. Can't get it to work. Keep getting messages stating it remains unchanged.